# click Button show error message in android

Tags: android

When I click Button show error message :unfortunately, learn has stopped
what is error here

button code:

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent i1 = new Intent(v.getContext(),Letters.class); 
i1.putExtra("Ar", "a5");
startActivity(i1);
}

});
```

and this is letters.java code:

what is error and how fixed it.

```
package com.example.learn;

import com.example.learn.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.*;
    public class Letters extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_letters);
            ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout1);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            String Ar_let=extras.getString("Ar");
            Toast.makeText(this, Ar_let, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(Ar_let=="a1")
            {
                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ar_a);
                rl.addView(image, lp);
            }
            else if(Ar_let=="a2")
            {
                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ar_b);
                rl.addView(image, lp);
            }
            else if(Ar_let=="a3")
            {
                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ar_c);
                rl.addView(image, lp);
            }
            else if(Ar_let=="a4")
            {
                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ar4);
                rl.addView(image, lp);
            }
            else if(Ar_let=="a5")
            {
                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ar5);
                rl.addView(image, lp);
            }
            else
            {
                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ar5);
                rl.addView(image, lp);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.letters, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

what is error please??!!

I remove Letters.java and add again but the same thing

Comment: Add the logcat view and see the exact exception. If you still need help, paste the exception here. Most likely, looking at the code, you didn't declare the Letters activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: <activity

android:name="com.example.learn.Letters"

android:label="@string/title_activity_letters" >

</activity>

Comment: message exception:
unfortunately, learn has stopped

Comment: post your full logcat error? and your Letters.java class as well

Comment: Add Letters.java code please help me my friend

Comment: Start by checking the [logcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588061/how-to-debug-android-project?rq=1) for the exception which caused your app to crash.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what causes the error, but I had the same problem. If I were you, I would try this, because it worked for me.

Add the following line to the xml code of your button:

```
 android:onClick="startNewActivity"
```

Then the xml of your button should look approximately like this:

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your Text" 
    android:onClick="startNewActivity" />
```

Use the Java code:

```
public void startNewActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Letters.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

You have to add the following lines to the import section:

```
import android.view.View;
android.content.Intent;
```

**Edit:** Oh, and I am not sure if you need to do this, but I would add this line in the Letter.Class onCreate() method. It is certainly good to make that a habit, because in a later project you might want to send information to the second activity. So, add this line to Letters.class:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Answer (score 0):

it's most probably because you are using `v.getContext();`
why don't you try something like :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myFirstClass.this,MySecondClass.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen the LogCat, but in your receiving Activity you're trying to receive a Bundle that you did not pass in. You passed in only a String, so use Intent.getStringExta() instead of a Bundle

```
String received = getIntent().getStringExtra("Ar");
```